# como apuntar un pedazo de mi web a otro servidor?

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, dns, seo

Utilizo Hostinger como servicio de host. Tengo una web, que incluye ademas de mi sitio, un monton de sitios de clientes, una intranet y demas cosas.

Recientemente, mande a hacer mi website nuevo, y me lo hicieron en netlify, asi que ahora, lo que quiero es que cuando alguien ingrese "www.midominio.com" o "midominio.com" aupnte a netlify (otro hosting), sin mostrar la URL del otro hosting, pero que cuando alguien quiera ir a "www.midominio.com/clienteA/" o "midominio.com/clienteA/" continue buscando en mi hosting actual

Que puedo hacer?

Ya probe, lo siguiente, sin exito:

- agregar en mi host actual, un registo A apuntando a la IP del nuevo host, y un CNAME para wwww apuntando a la url del nuevo host. Esto hace que al poner midominio.com se vea la web en el nuevo hosting correctamente, pero todo el resto de mi web quede inaccesible
- agregar solo CNAME a url del nuevo host, para "www", y forzar mediante htaccess que todo tenga "www", esto no me sirve, porque midominio.com/clienteA es forzado a ser [www.midominio.com/clienteA](http://www.midominio.com/clienteA), y no lo encuentra
- usar urlmasking no esta permitido en mi plan actual
- usar un iframe no es una opcion, asi como cualquier cosa que afecte el SEO de mi sitio

Comment: No sé si es que no entendí bien, pero el hecho que cambies de hosting no afecta tu dominio. Supongo que migraste todo de Hostinger a Netlify, es así?

Comment: no, no migré nada. solo contrate un servicio de diseño web para que me hagan una web nueva, y me la hicieron en netlify. Yo ya tengo hosting y un monton de trabajos hechos en mi hosting actual, y no quiero (ni puedo, ya que netlify no almacena webs estaticas) y quiero que mi web apunte a este servicio (netlify), sin perder todo lo demas (mi intranet, y todos mis trabajos)

Answer (score 0):

hay varias opciones, depende de tu forma de actuar o en la situación especifica de tu proyecto

1. dejate de cosas prehechas generales y instala un webserver en un vps tipo nginx que puedes hacer lo que quieras o contrata un servicio de administración con alguien del servidor
2. mantente en software's generalistas, pasa tu dominio por cloudflare, crea un registro A con el nombre por ejemplo client.midominio.com apuntando al servidor antiguo igual que está ahora y haz un page rule que redirija (301) de [www.midominio.com/clienteA/](http://www.midominio.com/clienteA/) hacia client.midominio.com/clienteA/

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-#h_38Gq7mduJiXIjpVLxp3q19

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: lo siento, he intentado meterme en la situación y especificar para que es mejor cada cosa, y eso es así por experiencia, ahora te parece bien? @gbianchi, puedes hacer esto o aquello, simplemente queria especificar segun mi experiencia, yo mismo he optado por ambas alternativas pero creia necesario decir que te limitas, sus ventajas y sus inconvenientes de cada cosa porque sino va a hacer esto y en 2 meses se va a encontrar que no puede hacer más de 3 page rules... suelo preferir una solicitud de edición con un comentario de porque antes que esto está mal arreglalo

Comment: y de esta forma hacer un comentario tal vez mejor estructurado que un simple (esto y esto y esto)

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, pero ya tengo un hosting VPS en hostinger, y aun asi no encuentro solucion.